# Change the word Tags into Keywords in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the single product page of a wordpress/woocommerce site are the Categories and Tags displayed.
It looks like: Tags: adri, Hellevoetsluis. The word Tags: must be changed into Keywords. 
I was searching in the template files if I could change it there. I didn't find it. Have I overlooked something?
See screenshot.

[image]

Please advice

Comment: Please provide more information if you want a fast answer. Otherwise, your question is currently discouraging people to help you :( Oh no~

Comment: @Daniel, thank you I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I did overlooked something. It is in the meta.php template file.
Problem solved.